# Objective-C Static Library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, static-libraries

I currently sell a static library and one of my clients is asking for "Generate Debug Symbols" to be turned on to help them debug any issues.  My concern is they'll be able to use this to see my source code or any information I may not want them to see.

Do debug symbols allow my library to be reverse engineered or does it allow them to view source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows them to see the variable names and routine names in the debugger.  It does not expose the source code.  It might make it slightly easier to reverse engineer, but not a whole lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does make it easier for them to reverse engineer your code. But you should also see this as something positive! If you include debug symbols it will be easier for them to debug any errors, and they may help you fix them.